# How to bypass upcasting and achieve polymorphism without virtual and override in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

I have three classes called `Animal`, `Cat` and `Dog` where `Cat` and `Dog` inherit from `Animal`:

```
public class Animal
{
    public void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent");
    }
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public new void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child(Cat)");
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public new void Talk()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child(Dog)");
    }
}
```

I have another method in another class that calls the `Talk()` method on an animal:

```
public static Animal FirstKindOfTalk(Animal animal)
    {
        if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Cat))
        {
            var changed = animal as Cat;

            if (changed is not null)
                changed.Talk();

            return changed;
        }
        else if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Dog))
        {
            var changed = animal as Dog;

            if (changed is not null)
                changed.Talk();

            return changed;
        }
            
        return animal;
    }
```

`FirstKindOfTalk(new Animal());` => **Parent** gets printed in the console.
`FirstKindOfTalk(new Cat());` => **Child(Cat)** gets printed in the console.
`FirstKindOfTalk(new Dog());` => **Child(Dog)** gets printed in the console.

I have to explicitly cast the parameter to their own type (Cat or Dog) due to **Upcasting**, in order to be able to run the specific implementation of those classes from the method `Talk()`. This is because I'm not using virtual and override in my code, if I used them, then the runtime would run the implementation of the passed in parameter from the method.

**The Problem**
I prefer to write the method as the following:

```
public static Animal SecondKindOfTalk(Animal animal)
    {
        var changed = animal;
        if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Cat))
        {
            changed = animal as Cat;

            changed.Talk();

            return changed;
        }
        else if (animal.GetType() == typeof(Dog))
        {
            changed = animal as Dog;

            changed.Talk();

            return changed;
        }

        return changed;
    }
```

`FirstKindOfTalk(new Animal());` => **Parent** gets printed in the console.
`FirstKindOfTalk(new Cat());` => **Parent** gets printed in the console.
`FirstKindOfTalk(new Dog());` => **Parent** gets printed in the console.

Can someone explain to me, what is causing this behavior?

I know using virtual and override is the better way, but I have to work on an existing project where methods from the base class aren't defined as virtual, and I cannot change them either.

Comment: You can shorten the code to `if (animal is Cat cat) { cat.Talk(); }` and remove the `return` inside the `if` as it's the same object anyway.

Comment: In general, **please** avoid using the `new` modifier to hide (not replace, not override) already existing members with "new" members. Instead, either use `virtual` and `override`. Or pick different names so no hiding occurs, and no confusion arises. In your case, call the method `public void Meow()` on `Cat`, and use `public void Bark()` on `Dog`, and keep `public void Talk()` on the base class. Because this naming reflects the reality: You have three unrelated methods, and you can call them only on the instances where they exist. But this removes most of your confusion!

Comment: The explanation is that C# is a _statically typed_ language, and when you write something like `.Talk`, the _binding_ occurs at compile-time, i.e. before you even start running the program, and based on the static compile-time type of the variable (or other expression) on which you use `.Talk`. This binding is final. It will not suddenly move to another member `.Talk` when the program runs and it turns out the _run-time type_ of the object is more derived than the compile-time type.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone explain to me, what is causing this behavior?

Yes - the compile-time type of `changed` in `SecondKindOfTalk` is still `Animal` , so you're still calling `Animal.Talk()` regardless of the execution-time type.

It would be simpler to use pattern matching in a switch statement:

```cs
public static Animal Task(Animal animal)
{
    switch (animal)
    {
        case Cat cat:
            cat.Talk();
            break;
        case Dog dog:
            dog.Talk();
            break;
    }
    return animal;
}
```

Or potentially even a switch expression and a delegate (which is slightly less performant, admittedly):

```cs
public static Animal Talk(Animal animal)
{
    Action action = animal switch
    {
        Cat cat => cat.Talk,
        Dog dog => dog.Talk,
        _ => null
    };
    action?.Invoke();
    return animal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone explain to me, what is causing this behavior?

Usage of `var` which is just an [implicitly-typed local variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#implicitly-typed-local-variables) declaration, i.e.

```cs
public static Animal SecondKindOfTalk(Animal animal)
{
    var changed = animal;
```

is the same as (`var` is handled by compiler during compile time)

```
public static Animal SecondKindOfTalk(Animal animal)
{
    Animal changed = animal;
```

And the following handling does not change the variable type, so the `Animal.Talk` will be used.

Check out the [type-testing operators and cast expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast)  doc for some patterns which can be used, like pattern matching:

```cs
public static Animal SecondKindOfTalk(Animal animal)
{
    if (animal is Cat cat)
    {
        cat.Talk();
    }
    else if (animal is Dog dog)
    {
        dog.Talk();
    }

    return animal;
}
```

P.S.

Note that `changed` variable name and attempt to return it kind of imposes some misunderstanding here. No actual change is done to the passed `animal`, it remains the same instance, i.e. `object.ReferenceEquals(changed, animal)` is `true`.